# Xpath - how to exclude nodes that contain attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xpath to obtain all text within text nodes like this:

```
<text>I want this text</text>
```

but I do not want to obtain text from nodes that contain an attribute like this:

```
<text name="contact">I DO NOT want this text</text>
```

Excluding text nodes that have a "name" attribute should work but I'd prefer to exclude text nodes that have any attribute to be more robust.  Is there a way to do this?

The Xpath below works to grab all text except it also grabs what I want excluded.

```
//*[local-name()='text'][string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not(@*)` predicate should do the trick:

```
//*[local-name()='text' and not(@*)][string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]
```

This should return you only `text` nodes without any attributes

Comment: That gives me exactly what I was after! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

> to exclude text nodes that have any attribute to be more robust

Short **`xpath`** expression:

```
//text[count(@*)=0]
```